PatientMedicalProcedureHistory is not available for both standard and custom reporting, how do I overcome that and build a report on it?
I can't select PatientMedicalProcedureHistory object when I create a custom report type and I can't find any standard report like that.
why?
PatientMedicalProcedureHistory is not available for both standard and custom reporting, how do I overcome that and build a report on it?

Are fields on the PatientMedicalProcedure object enabled under the Reports & Dashboards > Historical Trending section in Setup & is field history tracking enabled for the object? I don't have access to Health Cloud to dig into this, unfortunately.

Sadly, not all standard entities are enabled for history reporting so you'll need to create a Salesforce case to confirm that's the case and if they'll treat that as a known issue.

PatientMedicalProcedure object is not not available  under the Reports & Dashboards > Historical Trending section in Setup

